# An AMO-approved way of injecting a script into a document

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I'm developing a [cross-browser extension for Battlelog](https://github.com/jeremejevs/battletag) (online game launcher and social platform for Battlefield series).

For it to function properly, it needs to access page's JS environment, since the whole website is a huge and complicated client-side application, and it wouldn't make sense for me to try and replicate it, while all the functionality I need is right there.

Anyway, I've rolled out a working extension last week and submitted it to AMO for a review. Several hours ago I get a response:

> Your version was rejected. Your add-on creates DOM nodes from HTML
>   strings containing unsanitized data, by assigning to innerHTML or
>   through similar means. Aside from being inefficient, this is a major
>   security risk. For more information, see
>   https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL_School/DOM_Building_and_HTML_Insertion

Clearly, this is because of [this content script](https://github.com/jeremejevs/battletag/blob/master/common/inject.js):

```js
var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];

var css = document.createElement('link');
css.setAttribute('rel', 'stylesheet');
css.setAttribute('type', 'text/css');
css.setAttribute('href', @@CSS@@);
head.appendChild(css);

var js = document.createElement('script');
js.setAttribute('type', 'text/javascript');
js.setAttribute('src', @@JS@@);
head.appendChild(js);
```

While I agree, that it's dirty, I don't see how that is a security risk or inefficient in any way. There's no "unsanitized" data in it: `@@CSS@@` and `@@JS@@` get replaced with `self.data.url('battletag.css')` and `self.data.url('battletag.js')` respectively during the build process.

I'm looking into a way to make the extension work without tapping into page's context (which is possible, of course), but I would really like to NOT do that, especially that there are several features on the way, which make heavy use of page's data. The link provided in the response wasn't useful at all, since my injection script is basically a stripped down version of JSON Templating.

Is there a "legal" way to load a JS file into a document?

Answer (score 1):

Your code looks fine I don't know why the rejected it.

But what they want to see is this:

```
 var injectJsonCss = [
    'link', {
        rel: 'stylesheet',
        type: 'text/css',
        href: 'chrome://your-path-set-in-the-chrome.manifest-file/content/your-style.css'
    }
 ];

 var injectJsonScript = [
    'script', {
        type: 'stylesheet',
        type: 'text/javascript',
        src: 'chrome://your-path-set-in-the-chrome.manifest-file/content/your-script.js'
    }
 ];

jsonToDOM(injectJsonCss, document.head, {}); //inject the css
jsonToDOM(injectJsonScript, document.head, {}); //inject the script
```

**make sure that document is the contentDocument of the website**

and paste in your code this library stuff which is taken off that page

```
jsonToDOM.namespaces = {
    html: "http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml",
    xul: "http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul"
};
jsonToDOM.defaultNamespace = jsonToDOM.namespaces.html;
function jsonToDOM(xml, doc, nodes) {
    function namespace(name) {
        var m = /^(?:(.*):)?(.*)$/.exec(name);
        return [jsonToDOM.namespaces[m[1]], m[2]];
    }

    function tag(name, attr) {
        if (Array.isArray(name)) {
            var frag = doc.createDocumentFragment();
            Array.forEach(arguments, function (arg) {
                if (!Array.isArray(arg[0]))
                    frag.appendChild(tag.apply(null, arg));
                else
                    arg.forEach(function (arg) {
                        frag.appendChild(tag.apply(null, arg));
                    });
            });
            return frag;
        }

        var args = Array.slice(arguments, 2);
        var vals = namespace(name);
        var elem = doc.createElementNS(vals[0] || jsonToDOM.defaultNamespace,
                                       vals[1]);

        for (var key in attr) {
            var val = attr[key];
            if (nodes && key == "key")
                nodes[val] = elem;

            vals = namespace(key);
            if (typeof val == "function")
                elem.addEventListener(key.replace(/^on/, ""), val, false);
            else
                elem.setAttributeNS(vals[0] || "", vals[1], val);
        }
        args.forEach(function(e) {
            elem.appendChild(typeof e == "object" ? tag.apply(null, e) :
                             e instanceof Node    ? e : doc.createTextNode(e));
        });
        return elem;
    }
    return tag.apply(null, xml);
}
```

## ***EDIT ON SECOND THOUGHT***

Are you setting any innerHTML with the scripts in your script.js?

Comment: I was so focused on thinking that inject.js was at fault... Yes, I do set innerHTML in my [main script](https://github.com/jeremejevs/battletag/blob/master/common/battletag.js) (lines 29-46). I'll rewrite it using jQuery templating. Thanks for the second thought! I'll mark this as the answer if the add-on passes the review.

Comment: Cool man. You can use the same thing above, in your main script in place of jquery, but jquery would save you code. If you want to see how that is done with the code above let me know.

Comment: I've tried using it before, in an attempt to fix inject.js. The problem with `jsonToDOM` is that it's completely Firefox-centric. Hell, it won't even work in Chrome, since there's no `Array.slice` :) I'll stick to jQuery, it's a part of the target website anyway.

Comment: Ah I didn't know that. Thanks for sharing! Edit: wait, theres gotta be a slice function in Chrome... Thats been around since like day 1 of javascript

Comment: There is, but it's called `Array.prototype.slice` :D I just wanted to emphasize the fact that it's not "production-ready".

Comment: Can't you just do `arguments.slice(2)`? Don't get confused by the term prototype: http://javascriptissexy.com/javascript-prototype-in-plain-detailed-language/

Comment: @Luckyrat isn't `Array.prototype.slice` the same thing as `Array.slice`?

Comment: Yes I think so but the former works cross-browser. This might be of interest to: http://siegerstein.com/archives/302

Comment: Ah that article isvery interesting @Luckyrat